# Wilcard Sub-directories on webserver

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver, wildcard

I'm trying to figure out how to have wildcard sub-directories on my webserver. In example:

```
domain.com/1/weiurfda83/
domain.com/1/weiu9234usd/
domain.com/1/fj4329fj/
```

etc would go to `domain.com/1/` without redirecting

Also

```
domain.com/1/weiurfda83/1.jpg
domain.com/1/weiu9234usd/1.jpg
domain.com/1/fj4329fj/1.jpg
```

etc would go to `domain.com/1/1.jpg` without redirecting.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in `/1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```